# How can I exclude preloads with soft deleted join table associations

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

Using Elixir, Ecto.Query, Postgres

I have an association between `User` and `Location` through a join table `UserLocation`. I use `deleted_at` as a soft delete and check `is_nil(ul.deleted_at)` in when querying.
If I soft delete the join table record I will have

```
%User{id: 1, name: "larskris", deleted_at: nil, location: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :location is not loaded>}
%UserLocation{id: 25, user_id: 1, location_id: 13, deleted_at: #DateTime<2018-01-17 18:01:45Z>}
%Location{id: 13, address: "Some street", deleted_at: nil}
```

How can I run an Ecto query that will prevent the preload of these "deleted" locations?

```
Repo.one(
  from u in User,
  left_join: ul in UserLocation, on: a.id == ul.activity_id and is_nil(ul.deleted_at),
  left_join: l in Location, on: ul.location_id == l.id and is_nil(l.deleted_at),
  where: u.id == ^user_id
  and is_nil(u.deleted_at),
  preload: [:location]
)
```

The above returns the user but also preloads the location that should be nil. I always want the user even if there is no location associated.

Everything I've tried so far preloads the soft deleted location(s)

Separately querying locations and users and then map over them to build up what I need works but is not ideal.
Using the built in association also returns the soft deleted locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may just be a matter of using `preload` to use the LEFT JOINs (I think your given syntax does a whole new preload on its own).

```elixir
from u in User,
left_join: ul in UserLocation, on: a.id == ul.activity_id and   is_nil(ul.deleted_at),
left_join: l in Location, on: ul.location_id == l.id and is_nil(l.deleted_at),
where: u.id == ^user_id and is_nil(u.deleted_at),
preload: [location: l]
```

See the [Ecto docs for preload()](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.2.8/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3) for further details.

Comment: Thank you, been stuck for hours. The query I was working with was a bit more complex than the problem I isolated in the question. The user location part is nested. The link helped me solve that as well by using something like preload: [organization: {o, user: {u, location: l}}]. I was using a group_by as well and had to add o.id, u.id and l.id to the group_by list and it worked. Awesome, thanks!